# Ubuntu cakephp 2.2 console path set

Tags: path, console, cakephp-2.0, ubuntu-12.04

I am currently using Ubuntu 12 and trying to run cakephp's latest stable version, cakephp 2.2 and bake my files from console.

When i type `cake bake`, it shows old console version as below:

`Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.7 Console`

Do anyone have any idea, how can i update to CakePHP version 2.2?

Earliest response will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It run successfully with newer version of cake via below command:

```
/path/to/cake_2_2_0/app/Console/cake.php bake
```

you just need to change to the app directory within the the application and run